# Accessing advanced datagrid renderer elementns

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.5

In the AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider, i have assigned customItemRender for the renderer property.

This is my code:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="productADG" dragEnabled="true" displayItemsExpanded="true"
        dropEnabled="true" variableRowHeight="true"
        headerHeight="40" minHeight="5000" height="1000" 
        sortableColumns="false" 
        sortExpertMode="true" width="100%"                                                    
        defaultLeafIcon="{null}" folderOpenIcon="{null}"
        openDuration="400" headerWordWrap="true" >

    <mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:HierarchicalData id="hd" source="{productXML.product}" />
    </mx:dataProvider>

    <mx:columns>
          <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@productName" headerText="Product"  
                 width="120" wordWrap="true"/>
          <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="@descriptionTxt" headerText="Description" 
                 width="165" wordWrap="true"/>
          <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn width="145" headerText="Tools" id="toolsCol" 
                 resizable="false"/>
    </mx:columns>

    <mx:rendererProviders>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridRendererProvider id="compRend" depth="2" 
                renderer="customItemRender" column="{toolsCol}"/>
    </mx:rendererProviders>
</mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

customItemRender.mxml

```
<mx:HBox width="100%">
   <mx:Button id="editBtn"/>
</HBox>
```

How we can access the "editBtn" from the customItemRenderer in the main page(Datagrid resides)

I want to dispatch click event manually from the main page(Datagrid resides)..

Comment: mind if I ask why you want to force an event from the button?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about mx components, but in Spark, you can access items from an itemRenderer with getElementAt().

```
var renderer:customItemRender = productADG.getElementAt(0) as customItemRender;
```

Maybe mx has an equivalent to this?

But in your case, it sounds like you just want to do some specific functionality when the edit button is clicked. I would suggest dispatching a custom event from within the ItemRenderer when the button is clicked. Make sure the event bubbles. In the main page just listen for the custom event on the DataGrid.

customItemRender.mxml

```
<mx:HBox width="100%">
   <mx:Button id="editBtn" click="dispatchEvent(new Event('SomethingHappened', true));"/>
</HBox>
```

In the main page just add an event listener for 'SomethingHappened'.